# Match of routes in the collection

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, collections, routes, match

I define each actions in my controller this way (in `routes.rb`):

```
  resources :home do
    collection do
      get "home/index"
      get "home/about_me"
      get "home/contact"
    end
  end
```

If I would use a match for the action **about_me**, I have to use

```
      resources :home do
        collection do
          get "home/index"
          get "home/about_me"
          get "home/contact"
        end
      end

      match 'about-me' => 'home#about_me'
```

Exist any way, how to add `match` rule direct into a collection? I mean something like this:

```
  resources :home do
    collection do
      get "home/index"
      get "home/about_me", match => "about-me"
      get "home/contact"
    end
  end
```

And I have one question yet - when I use in the `routes.rb` the second block of code, so when I set the URL address `about-me`, so the address works fine, but when I type there `home/about_me`, so I get the error

> **Unknown action: The action 'show' could not be found for HomeController**.

What caused this error?

Comment: Using hyphens in urls in Rails is sort of messy; I recommend just accepting the default underscores to sidestep the issue entirely.

Comment: I forgot to answer your other question. I updated my answer now, check it out!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the problem here is that your routes have the `home/` prefix when they are nested inside `resources :home`. Try this:

```
 resources :home do
   collection do
     get :index
     get :about_me
     get :contact
   end
 end
```

Also, when you have trouble setting your routes, type `rake routes` in your console. This will generate the routes of your app and the corresponding paths and controllers.

EDIT: Here's the answer to your other question.

```
resources :home do
  collection do
    get 'about_me' => 'about-me'
  end
end
```